# Searching for a matching map name in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, search, demo

sorry i really dont know how to properly ask this question.
I would like to parse CS:GO Demo files in Powershell, and i would like to retrive the map name from it.

I opening dem files like this:
Get-Content $demo | Select -First 1 | Select-String -Pattern 'de_'

And i get this as response:

```
HL2DEMO    đ5  MatchServer I.                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                        GOTV Demo                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                de_mirage                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                        csgo                
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                     @#A  g   uÔ ~ř˙˙                                                                                                                                                   
            ą     Vđk (8wEÄü€ŢMĐhZăU    X@`śh u   <zcsgo‚   de_mirageŠ ’sky_dustšGOTV¨ ° ¸      ( 0 ž
```

I would like to get only the de_mirage as a variable. So if a map changes, then it will be de_dust2 or de_inferno and so on. Does anybody know a solution for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `Get-Content`, each line is passed down the pipeline **one** at a time, unless specifying the `-Raw` *switch*. The reason I bring this up is due to your `Select` cmdlet that you're piping to. When you specified the parameter of `-First`, with a value of `1`, you're only grabbing the first line, and then trying to find the pattern in the first line.

Here's my poor attempt at *RegEx*:

```
Get-Content -Path $demo | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_ -match 'de_\w+' }
$Matches[0]
```

. . .where the `$Matches` [Automatic Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2) contains all the matched *RegEx* patterns (*as the name indicates*) stored in an array format; where we use the index number to reference the value. This would also work piping to `Select-String` when searching for a Pattern just like you had done.

Comment: Solved by this:
$getMap = Get-Content $demo | Select -First 1 | Select-String -Pattern 'de_' | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_ -match 'de_\w+' }
$playedOnMap = $matches[0]

echo $playedOnMap

Thank you so much!